# GeoRegionValuePlot with a custom color function

Tags: graphics, color, legending, geographics

I used unscaled coordinates with a custom color function to visualize data for life expectancy in African countries (see code below). Five intervals for five colors. But it seems tha WM choses the boundaries of the intervals somehow different. What's the problem? Thanks!

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[ EntityClass["Country", "Africa"] -> "LifeExpectancy", ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> (Which[70 < #, Pink, 65 < # <= 70, Blue, 60 < # <= 65, Green, 55 < # <= 60, Gray, 50 < # <= 55, Orange] &), ImageSize -> 350, GeoLabels -> ((Tooltip[#1, Row[{#2, Spacer[5], #4}]] &))]
```

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1781256).

Answer (score 2):

OP's color function:

```
ClearAll[cF]
cF = Which[70 < #, Pink, 65 < # <= 70, Blue, 60 < # <= 65, Green, 
    55 < # <= 60, Gray, 50 < # <= 55, Orange] &;

grvp = GeoRegionValuePlot[ 
  EntityClass["Country", "Africa"] -> "LifeExpectancy",  
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> cF, 
  ImageSize -> 350, 
  GeoLabels -> ((Tooltip[#1, Row[{#2, Spacer[5], #4}]] &))]
```

[image]

As a work-around, you can create a `BarLegend` using your color function `cF` or the list of colors and specifying the list of contours in the second argument:

```
range = Range[50, 75, 5];
legend = BarLegend[{cF, {50, 75}}, range];
legend2 = BarLegend[{{Orange, Gray, Green, Blue, Pink}, {50, 75}}, range];
Row[{legend, legend2}]
```

[image]

and replace the legend in `grvp` with `legend`:

```
grvp /. _BarLegend -> legend
```

[image]

You can also use `legend` with `Legended` after extracting the plot from `grvp` (its firt `Part`):

```
Legended[grvp[[1]], Placed[legend, Right]]
```

> same picture

Note: I would have expected that using the option `PlotLegends -> legend` in `GeoRegionValuePlot` would have fixed the issue; it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I'm afraid it's not all tha simple.As a result you get 2 different pictures, that is Africa and legend and they are not connected. Just have a look at South Sudan in the center of the continent, Life expectancy is 56.811 yr. The initial legend that produced by GeoRegionValuePlot is correct but one cannot control it.

Comment: @GregoryFridman, not sure I follow. How come _" initial legend that produced by GeoRegionValuePlot is correct"_? Your color function says a country with life expectancy in $(55,60]$ (so South Sudan with LE 56.811) should be colored `Gray` (initial legend colors it Green), and the interval $(60, 65]$ should be mapped to `Green` (initial legend has `Pink` for that interval of values)

Comment: GeoRegionValuePlot generated the legend that corresponds to LE for countries (for instance, South Sudan is colored Blue and legend indicates "blue interval" for such values), But this legend does not correspond to my color function and this is the problem. On your picture the legend is okay (Blue color is from 65 to 70, etc.) but you may see that Sudan should be Gray, exactly as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a bug in `GeoRegionValuePlot`. You can fix it by executing the following code:

```
DownValues@System`GeoPlotsDump`iGeoRegionValuePlot = 
  DownValues@System`GeoPlotsDump`iGeoRegionValuePlot /. 
   HoldPattern@
     Rescale[
      #, 
      minMax : {0, 1} | PatternSequence[],
      {#2[[1]], Plus @@ #2}
     ] :> 
      Rescale[#, minMax, #2];
```

Now the code from the question works as expected:

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[
 EntityClass["Country", "Africa"] -> "LifeExpectancy",
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (Which[70 < #, Pink, 65 < # <= 70, Blue, 
     60 < # <= 65, Green, 55 < # <= 60, Gray, 50 < # <= 55, Orange] &),
 ImageSize -> 350,
 GeoLabels -> ((Tooltip[#1, Row[{#2, Spacer[5], #4}]] &))
 ]
```

[image]

### Why?

It seems the creator of `GeoRegionValuePlot` stumbled over the behavior of `Rescale`. The following is an excerpt of the code used to preprocess the given `ColorFunction` (in `` System`GeoPlotsDump`iGeoRegionValuePlot ``):

```
cf = (* some wrapper code… *) cfunc[
  If[
    TrueQ[cscaleQ],
    Rescale[#, {#2[[1]], Plus@@#2}],
    Rescale[#, {0, 1}, {#2[[1]], Plus@@#2}]
  ]
] (* some wrapper code… *)&;
```

Where `cf` is the processes `ColorFunction`, `cfunc` the `ColorFunction` specified in the options, and `cscaleQ` is `ColorFunctionScaling`. `cf` is called like this:

```
cf[#, {Min @ values, Max @ values}]& /@ {(* list of values between 0 and 1 *)}
```

So the second argument gives the range of the original data, which can directly be supplied as last argument to [`Rescale`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rescale.html), without the need to add anything together…

Comment: Lukas, thank you very much. It is exactly what I was looking for.